# Sliding window counter on Instagram API call

Tags: counter, instagram

I found that there is a limitation for calling Instagram API, the documentation said that the **limits on the Instagram Platform are applied on a sliding 1-hour window.**

What does 1-hour sliding window means and how does it computed?!

ref: https://instagram.com/developer/limits/#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1-hour sliding window means your api call limit will refresh after 1 hour.

```
Eg :  Authenticated Calls   5,000 / hour per token
Unauthenticated Calls   5,000 / hour per application
```

Comment: For example consider this sample. I make 1000 API calls on 6:10 and 4000 API calls on 6:20. Can I make another 1000 API calls on 7:10 or I should wait until 7:20 to have 5000 API call

Comment: YOu can hit next API call on 7:10 or 7:11 , because you started on 6:10